# How to destroy parent object with foreign key support on MySQL?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

Since Rails 4.2, foreign key support shows up, which automatically adds `add_foreign_key` to migration files.

But with MySql, when destroying parent object, the following error occurs.

```
user.destroy
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  Authentication Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `authentications`.* FROM `authentications` WHERE `authentications`.`user_id` = 5
  SQL (2.3ms)  DELETE FROM `authentications` WHERE `authentications`.`id` = 4
  Twitter Load (3.2ms)  SELECT  `twitters`.* FROM `twitters` WHERE `twitters`.`id` = 3 LIMIT 1
  SQL (1.7ms)  DELETE FROM `twitters` WHERE `twitters`.`id` = 3
  Follow Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `follows`.* FROM `follows` WHERE `follows`.`user_id` = 5
  Activity Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  `activities`.* FROM `activities` WHERE `activities`.`trackable_id` = 16 AND `activities`.`trackable_type` = 'Follow' LIMIT 1
  Feed Load (1.0ms)  SELECT `feeds`.* FROM `feeds` WHERE `feeds`.`activity_id` = 40
  Notification Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `notifications`.* FROM `notifications` WHERE `notifications`.`activity_id` = 40
  SQL (0.3ms)  DELETE FROM `notifications` WHERE `notifications`.`id` = 24
  SQL (1.8ms)  DELETE FROM `activities` WHERE `activities`.`id` = 40
  SQL (0.7ms)  DELETE FROM `follows` WHERE `follows`.`id` = 16
  Follow Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `follows`.* FROM `follows` WHERE `follows`.`followed_id` = 5
  SQL (11.2ms)  DELETE FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 5
Mysql2::Error: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`inq_development`.`notifications`, CONSTRAINT `fk_rails_c3860515c7` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`)): DELETE FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 5
   (0.5ms)  ROLLBACK
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`inq_development`.`notifications`, CONSTRAINT `fk_rails_c3860515c7` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`)): DELETE FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 5
from /Users/araky/git/inq_rails/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:299:in `query'
```

Above, I tried to destroy user which has many other objects.
I think if we try to delete parent row and children row at the same time on a single transaction, MySQL raises the error. ( I heard PostgreSQL handles those situation properly.)

How to destroy the parent row?
We have to remove foreign constraint? or Disable dependent option set in children model?

What's best practice?

Comment: add dependent destroy to the association. It shall solve your problem. I faced the same issue.

Comment: If you delete it in the right order, then mysql should do it in the same transaction. It seems you missed some notification - you could (and imho should - becasue of proper locking) delete them by user_id too, not select/delete by id.